# Prove that a commutative right primitive ring is a field

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Can anybody suggest how to prove or disprove the statement that every commutative right primitive ring is a field?

**Definition 1:** A ring is defined to be a set $(R,+, \cdot)$ with two binary operations, satisfying the following three axioms:

1. $(R, +)$ is an abelian group with non-trivial $0$ element,
2. $(R, \cdot)$ is a semigroup with unity,
3. the distributive identities are satisfied: for all $a, b, c \in R$, $a(b + c) = ab + ac$, $(a + b)c = ac + bc$.

**Definition 2:** A ring $R$ is called (right) primitive if there is a faithful simple right $R$-module.

**Definition 3:** A right $R$-module $M$ is called a faithful module if its annihilator in the ring $R$ is equal to zero; that is, for all $r \in R$, $M r = 0$ implies $r = 0$.

Comment: What does "right primitive" mean? I am actually curious, but it is also a hint to you on where to start: definitions, definitions, definitions. (Are your commutative rings assumed to contain $1$?)

Comment: Also, is the word "right" really necessary? What sort of property can still have left- and right versions in a commutative ring?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft well, the word is in the statement of the problem

Comment: @Arthur included the definitions.

Comment: What does it mean for a module to be exact?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I included the definition.

Comment: So now this $R$-module is generated by a single element, and that element is not killed by anything, making it just $R$ as a right module over itself.

Comment: I have never heard the phrase “exact module” used to mean “faithful module.” How very strange.

Comment: @rschwieb Neither had I, hence why I asked about it.

Comment: @rschwieb I make the changes now

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be a faithful simple right $R$ module.

By the first isomorphism theorem and the correspondence theorem, $S\cong R/T$ as a right $R$ module for some maximal ideal $T$.

But $T$ annihilates $R/T$, so $T=\{0\}$.

Since zero is a maximal ideal iff $R$ is a field, we’re done.